# iPod not recognised in Windows guest on Kubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, kde, ipod

I need to sync my iPod Touch (6th Gen) on a Windows 7 guest using VirtualBox on a Kubuntu machine. In this process, the iPod is not getting detected on the Windows host.

I have installed the guest additions on the guest OS and moreover, the iPod is detected on my Kubuntu machine (as 5th Gen!).

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 05ac:12aa Apple, Inc. iPod Touch 5.Gen [A1421]
```

When I was using Ubuntu, this issue did not occur and iPod got detected on the virtual machine without any configuration.

Is this a problem with KDE Plasma?
Is it possible to perform the sync?

Here some of the details about system:

```
OS: Kubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-45
KDE Plasma Version: 5.6.5
```

I have tried many VirtualBox versions:

```
Version 5.1.8-111374 with Extension Pack of the same version
Version 5.0.28-111378 with Extension Pack of the same version
Version 5.0.24-108355 (downloaded from Discover) with Extension Pack of the same version
```

Comment: Kubuntu version? Virtualbox version? Guestaddons version?

Comment: You probably have selected USB 2.0 (EHCI) controller after installing guestaddons ? It is a guess as I don't know what protocol iPod Touch is using for the sync. You can also add the specific device to the usb device list on that host machine.

Comment: I have tried with both the USB 2 and USB 3 controller, too!

Comment: Do you see the iPod in the usb list if you try the _add_ icon (with the green plus) in "Filter for USB devices" under USB ?

Comment: "no devices available", it shows.

Comment: Add `lsusb` line of the device, probably some kubuntu program had locked it... could be seen via `lsof` if it is a device file under _/dev_... not sure how to get which one (kernel log in dmesg) or smth...

Comment: I have added the `lsusb` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47834/discussion-between-rostislav-kandilarov-and-skrtbhtngr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I have found the solution to this particular problem.

After some help from [Rostislav](https://askubuntu.com/users/325029/rostislav-kandilarov), I discovered that none of my USB devices were being recognized in the VirtualBox itself!

- The Extension Pack was installed.
- The Guest Additions were installed in the Windows 7 guest machine.
- I had selected USB 2.0 as the controller in Settings.

I just needed to run `sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME vboxusers` (and then logout and login again)!
The installation process of VirtualBox did not do this automatically. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066190/1866196) answer helped me solve this issue.

If anyone else is having the same problem, you can check if you are a member of the `vboxusers` group or not.

```
cat /etc/group | grep vboxusers
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: If @RostislavKandilarov helped you reach a solution, you should encourage him to write up an answer here (as I do) because [a bounty can be awarded to any answer except one posted by the person offering the bounty.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) It sounds like he deserves it and you can't have it.

Comment: It's unfortunate that no one will get it.